# Does gold plating of Idols affect their energy?

Tags: worship, idols

We have Idols of *Vishnu*, *Sridevi* and *Bhudevi* of metal, dating back to many generations. We would like to gold plate the Idols. After they are gold plated what are we supposed to do so that the Idols can regain the Energy? If *prana prathishta* will help, how to do it?

Comment: Who said to you that gold plating causes lose to the *prana* of the *murty*? BTW, *pranapratishta* is only to be done to a *murthy* if you are sure that it's going to be worshiped with vedic rigor and is not just kept for ornamental purposes.

Comment: @VineetMenon, it's not question of whether gold or copper plating. anytime, a pratishta devata's tirumeni is modified with ulokas (metal combinations), it has to be accompanied with vedic rituals. so the answer is 'yes - gold (or any other metal) will cause loss of prana if not accompanied with vedas'